# FormData object returns empty even for a non-empty form

Tags: javascript, form-data

`FormData` object is empty for a form with 2 input fields. `formData.getAll()` logs a error `TypeError: Not enough arguments to FormData.getAll.`.
Here is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>

    <script>
      function test () {
        var element = document.getElementById("invite-form");
        console.log(element);
        var formdata = new FormData(element)
        console.log(formdata.getAll());
      }
    </script>

  </head>
  <body>

    <form id="invite-form" method='POST' action=''>
      <label for="email">Email...</label>
      <input type="text" name="email" value="human@earth.com"/>
      <input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="random" />
      <button class="btn" onclick="test()">Button</button>
    </form>

  </body>
</html>
```

I tried to populate the `FormData` object with the values from the form on clicking the button

Comment: You know that the `getAll()` method has somewhat spotty browser support, and really only works in Chrome 50+ and Firefox 39+

Comment: Yes I understand that but I am using the latest Firefox . I just want to know what I am doing wrong here

Comment: It works for me in Firefox, but as the [documentation states](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/getAll), it requires a key, something like `formdata.getAll('email')`

Comment: @adeneo thank you for pointing out the mistake. I failed to pass the key as argument.

Comment: No problem, I didn't know one had to pass a key either, I assumed it returned the entire form, but apparently, it doesn't

Comment: @adeneo You should add this as an answer. Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `getAll()` method of the FormData interface requires a key to be given.
It then returns all the values associated with that key from within a FormData object.

```
function test () {
    var element = document.getElementById("invite-form");
    console.log(element);
    var formdata = new FormData(element)
    console.log(formdata.getAll('email')); // <- needs key
}
```

Comment: This naming scheme is so dumb, `getAll` but it gets a single field